# NHibernate with SQLite Insert Performance Issue

Tags: c#, .net, performance, nhibernate, sqlite

I'm using NHibernate 3 with SQLite 3 (to be more precise - SQLCipher but it doesn't make sense in this case).

I have configured NHibernate like that:

```
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">Test.NHibernate.MySqliteDriver, nhibernate_test</property>     
        <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=embedded</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>  
        <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu, Version=3.0.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here, `Test.NHibernate.MySqliteDriver, nhibernate_test` is a custom driver that can handle connection string like `Data Source=embedded`. It doesn't do any specific operations except creating SQLiteConnection to memory DataSource and attaching one database to it with ATTACH instruction. It doesn't make a sense too.

I have a table:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Category { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Discontinued { get; set; }
}
```

Mapped to:

```
CREATE TABLE Prosucts (
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(250),
    Category VARCHAR(250),
    Discontinued INTEGER
);
```

With mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
                   assembly="nhibernate_test" 
                   namespace="Test.NHibernate.Domain">
    <class name="Product" table="Products">
        <id name="Id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="Name" />
            <property name="Category" />
            <property name="Discontinued" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In code i do the following:

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.Configure(typeof(Program).Assembly, "hibernate.cfg.xml");         
configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly);

var sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();

var product = new Product
{
    Name = "Product",
    Category = "Products",
    Discontinued = true
};

var product2 = new Product
{
    Name = "Product 12",
    Category = "Bad products",
    Discontinued = true
};

using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{               
    using(var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();         

        session.Save(product);
        Console.WriteLine("saved 1st in {0}", sw.Elapsed);
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();

        session.Save(product2);
        Console.WriteLine("saved 2nd in {0}", sw.Elapsed);
        sw.Stop();

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

And get a disapointing output:

NHibernate: INSERT INTO Products
(Name, Category, Discontinued) VALUES (@p0, @p1 , @p2); 
select last_insert_rowid();
@p0 = 'Product' [Type: String (0)], @p1 = 'Products' [Type: String (0)], @p2 = True [Type: Boolean (0)]

**saved 1st in 00:00:01.3444869**

NHibernate: INSERT INTO Products (Name, Category, Discontinued) VALUES (@p0, @p1 , @p2);
select last_insert_rowid();
@p0 = 'Product' [Type: String (0)], @p1 = 'Products' [Type: String (0)], @p2 = True [Type: Boolean (0)]

**saved 2nd in 00:00:00.0044215**

So why inserting 1st record takes so long??? (for 1.3 seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible sources:

1. initializing the session cache(s) when you give it the first entity to track, and
2. SQLite firing up its internals to generate that first native identity value

Comment: It is just waking up from the sleep and then running. Try with 3rd and 4th and so on and if lag is only with very first record, then it is normal and nothing to worry about.

Comment: Yep, the this is always with only first record. Btw, my further exploration have shown that it has no connection with NHibernate. With Linq2Sql - the same issue. So it's SQLite issue. But... is it a limitation or there is a workaround?